# Why doesn't my subclass' variable exist?

Tags: ios, swift

I made a subclass of `UILabel` called `UIScoreLabel`, which is more specialized for my need of displaying a score. Here is the code:

```
class UIScoreLabel: UILabel
{
    var scoreBackingInt: Int!
    var score: Int {
        get
        {
            return scoreBackingInt
        }
        set(newScore)
        {
            scoreBackingInt = newScore
            self.text = NSString(format: "%0\(digits)d", newScore)
        }
    }
    let digits: Int!    // number of digits to display (for 0-padding)

    init(digits: Int)
    {
        super.init()
        self.digits = digits
        self.score = 0
    }
}
```

`score` is supposed to be a computed variable. Anyway, everything is fine when I instantiate a UIScoreLabel, but when I attempt to access any of the subclass' properties in any way (i.e. `score`), the compiler tells me `'UILabel' does not have a member named 'score'`

Here is the line that gives me an error, in my ViewController:

```
creditsLabel.score = self.score
```

What gives?

Comment: Did you set the class for your creditsLabel to `UIScoreLabel` in the identity inspector in InterfaceBuilder?

Comment: We need to see the instantiation of your UIScoreLabel, as that's what's actually causing the problem.

Comment: @zisoft
`creditsLabel = UIScoreLabel(digits: 6)`
I'm not using the IB, I'm doing this programmatically.

Comment: @MichaelZimmerman You should edit your question and add that code snippet to make it explicit.

Comment: @MichaelZimmerman I don't see a `var` or `let` in the statement that initializes `creditsLabel`, is that part elsewhere or did you just omit it? If it's elsewhere, that'd be good to see too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to let the compiler know the class type. As you can see in the error message the compiler currently thinks the class is `UILable` so you need to update the class type (or cast the class type if you can't).

Comment: The compiler _should_ know it's a UIScoreLabel: `creditsLabel = UIScoreLabel(digits: 6)`

Comment: @MichaelZimmerman that line of code isn't in your question anywhere. Since it's the part that doesn't work, why didn't you include it in the question? Wain is correct, the compiler does not know that it's a `UIScoreLabel`, the error message indicates the compiler believes it is a `UILabel`.

Comment: @MichaelZimmerman, the definition of `creditsLabel` must be a `UILabel`so you need to change that or cast each usage...

Answer (score 2):

`UILabel` is a subclass of `UIView` and `UIView`'s default initializer is `init(frame: CGRect)`. This is the initializer that you need to use when you call super.

```
  super.init(frame: CGRectZero)
  self.digits = digits
  self.score = 0
```

Also `UILabel` adopts `NSCoding` and has a required init that you need to implement. Since you are not using storyboards, you can just add the following to get rid of the compiler error:

```
  required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented") 
  }
```